delete instance of factory boy from another one
I have two FactoryBoy and I tried to delete the first one from the second,
What I want to accomplish is when I delete a ShareLinksFactory instance, the associated WebShareFileFactoryBoy and its corresponding file should also be deleted.
Below is the class ShareLinksFactory:
class ShareLinksFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
class Meta:
    model = ShareLinks

id = factory.LazyFunction(create_id)
web_share_file_folder = factory.SubFactory(WebShareFileFactoryBoy)
create_user = UuidCifsUsers.objects.get(cifs_user='user_test').id
limit_datetime = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: timezone.now() + timedelta(days=30))
created_by_factory = True

WebshareFileFactoryBoy
class WebShareFileFactoryBoy(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
class Meta:
    model = WebShareFileFolders
    django_get_or_create = ('inode',)

name = factory.Faker('file_name', extension='txt')
path = factory.Faker('name')
inode = factory.Faker('random_number')
is_dir = False

@factory.post_generation
def create_file_on_disk(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.name + str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]  # these permit to make a unique name for the file
    automatic_folder_path = os.path.join(NAS_PATH, 'Share/automatic/')
    Path(automatic_folder_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    full_path = os.path.join(automatic_folder_path, str(self.name))
    file_size_mo = kwargs.pop('file_size_mo', None)

    with open(full_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(
            f'Name: {self.name} \n'
            f'Is a folder: {self.is_dir} \n'
            f'make with love: True \n'
            f'where: {full_path}'
        )

        if file_size_mo:
            file_size = file_size_mo * 1024 * 1024
            file.seek(file_size - 1)
            file.write('\0')

    self.inode = os.stat(full_path).st_ino
    self.path = 'Share/automatic/' + str(self.name)

    self.save()

    std, err, code = popen_wrapper([
        'sudo', '/set_webshare_extattr.sh',
        str(self.id),
        full_path
    ])

I try to overide the delete function from the class but I get an error
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model WebShareFileFolders: 'delete

